# Absolute position with :after

Tags: css, css-position

I have a very simple html code

```
<div>
    <h1>This is a test </h1>    
  </div>
```

with a super simple css

```
h1:after
{
background-color:red;
    content:'';    
    height:2px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

if I run this code(at least in Chrome), there was a red line right after the text
However, if I remove the line "position:absolute", this red line is also removed.

Can anyone help me to explain this situation ?

Comment: What do you want to? Please explain it clearly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:after` and `:before` pseudoelements are `inline` by default. As a default with an empty content the have zero size and you can't set them `width` and `height`.

If you want to see these pseudoelements, you need to make them absolutely positioned or set them `display: table/block`, etc.

Comment: I see. Therefore, can I understand that if we set an element "absolute" position, we make it become "block"?

Comment: @wraith: see this short fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kbujo198/. The first one is inline, `width: 0; height: 0;` due to the fact I set both, width and height. The second one is positioned absolutely, and has the size I set before. With the pseudoelements the situation is the same.